# traefik - Put variable into docker label

Tags: docker-compose, traefik

maybe is a stupid question...but it's possibile to put variable into docker labels of docker-compose.yml file?

my .env file:

```
HOST_1=www.example.com
HOST_2=www.site.com
```

into my docker-compose.yml file can you write like this?

```
services:
  site_01:
    ...
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.site_01.rule=Host(`${HOST_1}`)"
      - "traefik.http.services.site_01.loadbalancer.server.port=80"

  site_02:
    ...
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.site_02.rule=Host(`${HOST_2}`)"
      - "traefik.http.services.site_02.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is [possible](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#labels-2) and your snippet seem correct. You can check if the labels are there with `docker inspect <container_name_or_id>`.

It is also possible to add labels at the build stage. The syntax is the same but `labels:` key must be under `build:` key.

Comment: exactly as I wrote ... I thought it didn't work